# LESS CSS on WP8 and Cordova - FileError x-wmapp0

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, less, visual-studio-cordova

I get the following error on WP8 when using LESS CSS

> FileError: 'x-wmapp0:www/x-wmapp0:www/views/post/post.less' was not
>   found (404)

Has anyone else had the same issue before? I assume libraries such as require.js would have the same problem.
Only happens on WP8 - the rest seems to work fine

Comment: How are you using LESS? Do you just have the .less files in your project directory structure? Can you show us how you're referencing the less files in your pages?

Comment: I just reference them the head section as below `<link href="resources/styles/colour.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resources/styles/core.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />`

Comment: I was able to use LESS with WP8 Cordova app without any error. Can you post sample snippet which will help us repro the issue?

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek-MSFT. I will create a sample test app and upload it here